# Google Analytics recorded internal traffic while using Tag Assistant?

Tags: google-analytics, report, google-tag-manager

Just went to review a page and got excited at the page view metrics, however turns out half of them are from tag.assistant google (2 users, 120 page views)

I'm sure this is from when I was checking tags were installed correctly across the site.

Does this mean our GA is recording internal traffic?

Or is this just a common error that tag.assistant can cause?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is a common behavior when you set GTM in preview mode. To avoid it you have to add `tagassistant.google.com` to your Google Analytics **referral exclusion list** to avoid preview mode starting a new session.